# How to calculate a date before "given time" from current date, using class or instance method of NSDate class?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsdate

Need to calculate a date before a given time (let it be 10 years) from current date, and don't want to do this manually. Is there any default class or instance method for NSDate class which do this. I went through [NSDate Class reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDate_Class/Reference/Reference.html) but unable to get the desired response.

If there's no any then please suggest any proper way to achieve this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an example I use for calculating `monthsBack` worth of months, but you can substitute setMonth for setYear:

```
int monthsBack = [limitMonths.value intValue];
NSDateComponents *dateComponents = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
[dateComponents setMonth:-monthsBack];
NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
dLimitMonths = [calendar dateByAddingComponents:dateComponents toDate:[NSDate date] options:0];
```